# Issue with tabularx and hbox options in tcolorbox

Tags: tables, tabularx, tcolorbox

I'm having a problem with formatting a `tcolorbox` so that it contains a table and its width fits the width of the table. A MWE of my code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[skin = enhanced jigsaw, tabularx = {p{2cm}p{3cm}}, capture = hbox, breakable = false, title = {Test}, label = {test}, center]
        \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2}\tabularnewline\midrule
        1 & 2\tabularnewline
        3 & 4\tabularnewline
        5 & 6\tabularnewline
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

LuaLaTeX throws the following errors when trying to compile it:

```
Argument of \TX@get@body has an extra }. \end{tcolorbox}
Paragraph ended before \TX@get@body was complete. \end{tcolorbox}
Missing } inserted. \end{tcolorbox}
```

The same code compiles fine without the `hbox` option but I can't seem to find any information on the incompatibility between it and `tabularx`. Setting or unsetting explicit table column widths (e.g., with `p`) has no effect. Please advise.

Comment: please provide a small test document that shows the error, not a fragment. Note that `tabularx = {cc}`  looks wrong, there should always be at least one `X` column otherwise `tabularx` can do nothing useful.

Comment: Added a full MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the real problem is. Using `tabularx` without an `X` column is wrong to begin with.

Perhaps defining a new style modeled on `tabularx` is what you're looking for:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
  tabular/.style={
    boxsep=\z@,top=\z@,bottom=\z@,leftupper=\z@,rightupper=\z@,
    toptitle=1mm,bottomtitle=1mm,boxrule=0.5mm,
    before upper={\arrayrulecolor{tcbcol@frame}\def\arraystretch{1.1}%
      \tcb@hack@currenvir\tabular{#1}},
    after upper=\endtabular\arrayrulecolor{black}},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
  skin = enhanced jigsaw,
  tabular = {p{2cm}p{3cm}},
  capture = hbox,
  breakable = false,
  title = {Test},
  label = {test},
  center
]
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2}\tabularnewline\midrule
1 & 2\tabularnewline
3 & 4\tabularnewline
5 & 6\tabularnewline
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're right. And thanks, I believe this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\usepackage{tabularx, colortbl, booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tabularx = {XX}, breakable = false, title = {Test}, label = {test}, center]
    \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2}\tabularnewline\midrule
    1 & 2\tabularnewline
    3 & 4\tabularnewline
    5 & 6\tabularnewline
\end{tcolorbox}

\noindent X\dotfill X\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is this what is asked for ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, breakable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[skin = enhanced jigsaw, breakable = false,
      capture=hbox, title = {Test}, label = {test}, center]
      \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}p{3cm}}
        \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2}\tabularnewline\midrule
        1 & 2\tabularnewline
        3 & 4\tabularnewline
        5 & 6
      \end{tabular}
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't solve my problem, since in my actual code the table columns have set widths.

Comment: I don't know what your problem is...

Comment: See OP. I can't use the `X` specifier for my table and that doesn't solve the problem anyway, since it changes column widths instead of the width of the box.

Comment: The edited example is my current fallback solution but it's not optimal since I have to manually fit paddings etc., whereas using the `tabularx` option "fills" the colorbox with the table and overall seems to provide better integration.

Comment: @AretsPaeglis if you do not use `X` then use tabular not `tabularx`, `tabularx` without an `X` column can not do anything to achieve the specified width so it will just act like `tabular` but give underfull box warnings.

Comment: I do need it to act like `tabular`, just with the automatic adjustments `tcolorbox` makes, since my actual code has grown to the level of size and complexity (an entire book at this point) where manually tweaking the margins, paddings, etc. of all the tables is simply too much effort.

Using the `tabularx` option does almost what I need but *almost*, since the `hbox` option seems incompatible with it for some reason (or perhaps I'm simply doing something wrong).