# How to make lower part of tcolorbox as tall as the title

Tags: tcolorbox

How can I make the gray part as tall as the title box (the red part)? I tried changing `bottom` and `middle`, but `middle` changes the space between the text and the lower box (which I don't want), and even if it didn't I'd still be eyeballing all the measures.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\cornerwidth}
\setlength{\cornerwidth}{.5mm}
% --------------------------
\begin{document}
\tcbset{title={1 January 2001}, 
           center title, 
           halign lower=center, 
           boxrule=\cornerwidth,
           sharp corners,
           bicolor, 
           collower=black, 
           colback=white, 
           colframe=black!75, 
           colbacklower=black!40,
           colbacktitle=red,
           coltitle=black}

\begin{tcolorbox}[overlay={\draw[tcbcolframe, line width=\cornerwidth] (segmentation.west)--(segmentation.east);}]
\lipsum[1]
\tcblower
89.50
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In your [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496183/1952) I wanted to propose the use of a `tcbsubtitle` (which shares geometry with `title`) instead of a `lower` part. But I don't know how to avoid the empty line after that. If you find how to do it, I think you'll have a good solution for your problem.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496429/1952

Comment: `tcbsubtitlte` was my first solution but I changed idea for two reasons: 1) I can't find a way to extend the borderlines to makethe connectionwith the vertical ones seamless [this is what I mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496183/how-to-put-a-line-above-the-lower-part-of-tcolorbox/496288?noredirect=1#comment1253161_496288) 2) the empty line can technically beremoved with `after={\vspace{-<some>pt}}` in the `tcbsubtitle` options, butI didn't like that solution as I couldn't get the exact amount of space to subtract(basically the height of the white line plus the one of the border).

Comment: another problem with `tcbsubtitle` (which I just found out) is that it shares the geometry with title only in the “default“ case: for example, if I make the title `\Huge`, the title box will adjust but the subtitle one won't.

Comment: Yes, it's true. But you could always declare an special style which fixes these options for `title` and `tcbsubtitle` using the same parameter.

Comment: A special style can fix problem 3) (even if I wouldn't know how), but what about 1) and 2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to adjust `tcblower` part geometry to `title`, I propose to use a tricky solution: forget the `title` and `lowerbox` and use two `tcbsubtitle` commands automatically added with `before upper` and `after upper` options.

As `tcbsubtitle` are part of `tcolorbox` contents, they show a vertical distance from top and bottom borders. This vertical space defined by `boxsep` option can be compensated with a negative `top` and `bottom` values. These `top` and `bottom` values are applied to main `tcolorbox` but each subtitle can use different particular values.

As every `tcbtitle` is a more or less regular `tcbox` and not a `title` plus a `tcbox`, there's no need for particular options like `toptitle` in one and `top` into the other. We can define a general geometry and style for both subtitles but still use particular settings for top and bottom. Following code shows how to do it.

I think this code solves problems 1, 2 and 3 (see comments above).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% --

\tcbset{
    titlecommon/.style={
        fontupper=\Large\bfseries\sffamily,
        top=2mm,
        bottom=2mm,
        halign=center,
        sharp corners,
        leftrule=0.5mm, %to draw left side in subtitle box
        rightrule=0.5mm, %to draw right side in subtitle box
        opacityfill=.5,  %to test subtitles geometry and positioning
    },
    toptitle/.style={
        titlecommon,
        colframe=green,
        colback=green!20,
    },
    bottomtitle/.style={
        titlecommon,
        colframe=red,
        colback=red!20,
    },
}   

\newtcolorbox{twotitle}[3][]{
    enhanced,
    sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black!75,
    notitle,
    before upper={\tcbsubtitle[toptitle]{#2}},
    after upper={\tcbsubtitle[bottomtitle]{#3}},
    top=-1.5mm, %-boxsep-toprule
    bottom=-1.5mm, %-boxsep-bottomrule
    #1,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{twotitle}[colback=orange!20]{Title}{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\end{twotitle}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, good job.

Comment: If I try to change the color of the main text, for example to blue, with `fontupper=\color{blue}`, I get an extra line at the top before the title box. Why does it happen?

Comment: @noibe You should use `colupper=blue`, `fontupper` is used to fix font characteristics (boldface, size, serif, ...) but not it's color.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom strut to the title...that would be making the top line taller, rather than the lower line smaller.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\cornerwidth}
\setlength{\cornerwidth}{.5mm}
% ----------------------------
\newcommand\mystrut{\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{19pt}}
\begin{document}
\tcbset{title={1 January 2001\mystrut}, 
           center title, 
           halign lower=center, 
           boxrule=\cornerwidth,
           sharp corners,
           bicolor, 
           collower=black, 
           colback=white, 
           colframe=black!75, 
           colbacklower=black!40,
           colbacktitle=red,
           coltitle=black}

\begin{tcolorbox}[overlay={\draw[line width=\cornerwidth] (segmentation.west)--(segmentation.east);}]
\lipsum[1]
\tcblower
89.50
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This attempts to reduce the lower box height:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\cornerwidth}
\setlength{\cornerwidth}{.5mm}
% ----------------------------
\begin{document}
\tcbset{title={1 January 2001}, 
           center title, 
           halign lower=center, 
           boxrule=\cornerwidth,
           sharp corners,
           bicolor, 
           collower=black, 
           colback=white, 
           colframe=black!75, 
           colbacklower=black!40,
           colbacktitle=red,
           coltitle=black}

\begin{tcolorbox}[overlay={\draw[line width=\cornerwidth] (segmentation.west)--(segmentation.east);}]
\lipsum[1]
\tcblower \makebox{\smash{\raisebox{-3pt}{89.50}}}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But both of these solutions are hacks, I still need to eyeball the correct amount of space to add/subtract to make the two boxes the same height.