# Rounding the corners of tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

Taking the code from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496534/172923) excellent answer, how can I modify it to get rounded corners on all the frames?. I managed to round the main frame, but the other two are still straight:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% --

\tcbset{
    titlecommon/.style={
        fontupper=\Large\bfseries\sffamily,
        top=2mm,
        bottom=2mm,
        halign=center,
        sharp corners,
        leftrule=0.5mm, %to draw left side in subtitle box
        rightrule=0.5mm, %to draw right side in subtitle box
        opacityfill=.5,  %to test subtitles geometry and positioning
    },
    toptitle/.style={
        titlecommon,
        colframe=green,
        colback=green!20,
    },
    bottomtitle/.style={
        titlecommon,
        colframe=red,
        colback=red!20,
    },
}   

\newtcolorbox{twotitle}[3][]{
    enhanced,
    arc=5pt,
    % sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black!75,
    notitle,
    before upper={\tcbsubtitle[toptitle]{#2}},
    after upper={\tcbsubtitle[bottomtitle]{#3}},
    top=-1.5mm, %-boxsep-toprule
    bottom=-1.5mm, %-boxsep-bottomrule
    #1,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{twotitle}[colback=orange!20]{Title}{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\end{twotitle}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your link is not working, please edit your question.

Comment: It should work now.

Comment: @DavidPurton this would actually be relevant only for the first part of the box

Comment: @BambOo, yes I didn't read close enough. Just about to post an answer similar to yours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit of tweaking

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% --

\tcbset{
    titlecommon/.style={
        fontupper=\Large\bfseries\sffamily,
        top=2mm,
        bottom=2mm,
        halign=center,
        sharp corners,
        leftrule=0.5mm, %to draw left side in subtitle box
        rightrule=0.5mm, %to draw right side in subtitle box
        opacityfill=1,  %to test subtitles geometry and positioning
        arc=5pt,
    },
    toptitle/.style={
        titlecommon,
        colframe=green,
        colback=green!20,
        rounded corners=north,
    },
    bottomtitle/.style={
        titlecommon,
        colframe=red,
        colback=red!20,
        rounded corners=south,
    },
}   

\newtcolorbox{twotitle}[3][]{
    arc=5pt,
    enhanced,
    % sharp corners,
    colback=white,
    colframe=black!75,
    notitle,
    before upper={\tcbsubtitle[toptitle]{#2}},
    after upper={\tcbsubtitle[bottomtitle]{#3}},
    top=-1.5mm, %-boxsep-toprule
    bottom=-1.5mm, %-boxsep-bottomrule
    #1,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{twotitle}[colback=orange!20]{Title}{Test}
\lipsum[1]
\end{twotitle}
\end{document}
```

[image]